# Getting 3 points although the code describes 1 point in the plane

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, scripting

I'm trying to plot the closest point in the plane to the point P (the one that can be dragged) but in the graph appears 3 points.

in the graph I'm plotting a plane and a point P, I want to add another point Q which is the closest point between the point P and the plane, and a line that connect between them

*Note: the code might be a little bit messy
*I can't add all the code because its too long...

the code :

```
    Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pts = {{2, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 1}}, index = 0, pos0, pos1, 
   AV1Cap1Obj, F, P, t, Q, normal, sol0, Q1},
  
  F[x_, y_] := (a*x0 + b*y0 + c*z0 - a*x - b*y)/c;
  
  
  AV1Cap1Obj[var_] := 
   If[var == 1, {Thickness[0.0001], Arrowheads[0.00], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, 
    If[var == 2, {PointSize[0.04], Point[Dynamic@pts[[2]]], 
      FaceForm[], EdgeForm[], 
      Cuboid[Dynamic[pts[[2]] - {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}]]}]];
  
  P = Dynamic[pts[[2]]];
  normal = {a, b, c};
  sol0 = 
   Flatten[ 
    Solve[{0, 0, 
        1} . (P + t normal) == (a*x0 + b*y0 + c*z0 - 
         a*{1, 0, 0} . (P + t normal) - b*{0, 1, 0} . (P + t normal))/
       c, t ]];(*return {t->value}*)
  Q1 = P + t normal /. sol0;
  
  
  EventHandler[
   
   Show[{
     Graphics3D[{
       MouseAppearance[EventHandler[
           
           Mouseover[{(*Base expr,mouse out*)
             Dynamic[If[index === #, Red, Purple]], AV1Cap1Obj[#]},
            {(*Mouse over*)
             Dynamic[If[index === 0 || index === # , Red, Purple]], 
             AV1Cap1Obj[#]}](*Mouse Over*),
           
           {"MouseDown" :> (index = #;
              pos0 = pts[[index]])},
           PassEventsUp -> True] & /@ 
         Range[Length[pts]](*Event Handler Local,#1,2,...*), 
        "Arrow"]}
      , PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
      ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True](*Graphics3D*),
     
     (*new *)
     If[a == b == c == 0,
      Graphics3D[{Thick, Purple, Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, .25]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
       PlotLabel -> 
        Style["A plane can only be described by a non-zero vector.", 
         16, Red], Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
       ImageSize -> Large],
      
      Show[{
        
        Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, 
          Arrow[{{x0, y0, z0}, {x0, y0, z0} + 0.6 {a, b, c}}],
          
          Text[Style["P", 14, Black], {0.5, 0.5} + 
            Dynamic[pts[[2]]], {1, 0}],
          {Blue, Thickness[0.01], Line[{Q1, {pts[[2]]}}]},
(*here Im trying to plot point Q1 but it appears 3 points*)
          {Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[Q1]}
```

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is not complete.

Comment: I know that because it's too long, I can't post the whole code... I get an error message when I put all of it, I'm trying to add the whole code

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use RegionNearest. For example,

```
(* given some plane region... *)
plane = InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}];

(* ...and some point not on the plane... *)
point = {0, 0, 0};

(* ...you can use NearestRegion: *)
nearest = RegionNearest[plane, point]
(* {36/49, 18/49, 12/49} *)
```